# Formula to find b in y=mx+b

Tags: graphing-functions

I am trying find the formula to find `b` in `y=mx+b`. I have a scatter plot with 10 values. I have found `m` using `=(sxy - (sx * sy) / n) / (sxx - (sx)^2 /n)`. Now I need to find `b`. I have been looking everyplace I could think to but the best thing I found was this [$b=\frac{\displaystyle\sum _{i=1} ^ny_i-b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n}$](http://www.livephysics.com/tools/mathematical-tools/calculate-linear-regression-graph-scatter-plot-line-fit/), but I don't know what that means. Also, I know I can use built in functions, that misses the point. I also don't want to just take two points and figure our about where it goes.

```
 x    y
 9    9
 2    6
 9   81
 5   28
 8   65
 7   53
 5   27
10  100
 4   21
 4   17

m = 8.9844
```

Comment: In case by "*but I don't know what that means*" is in reference to the symbols used, the [$\sum$-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation) is used to describe summations.  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i = y_1+y_2+y_3+\dots+y_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo.

$$b=\frac{\displaystyle\sum _{i=1} ^ny_i-m\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n}$$

Are you able to compute $b$ now?

Answer (score 0):

The built in functions you refer to are using linear regression and least squares. [This](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~jennings/stat514/stat512notes/topic3.pdf) pdf gives a decent overview.  For your case if you construct a matrix X = [1 9; 1 2;1 9; 1 5; 1 8; 1 7; 1 5; 1 10; 1 4; 1 4] and Y = [9;6;81;28;65;53;27;100;21;17] then b = (X'X)^-1*X'Y=[-15.9017; 8.9844] The first number is b, the second your m.